# How to switch integer flags using bitshift in Java?

Tags: java, bit-shift

I have many objects in a matrix which are storing the connections to their neighbours in a single integer variable.

```
public static final int NONE = 0x00;
public static final int LEFT = 0x01;
public static final int TOP = 0x02;
public static final int RIGHT = 0x04;
public static final int BOTTOM = 0x08;

connections = LEFT | RIGHT | BOTTOM; // example usage
```

Now I want to be able to rotate certain objects by 90° CW or CCW. In the example above a clockwise rotation should be equivalent to

```
connections = TOP | BOTTOM | LEFT;
```

A left / right bitshift of 1 seems the obvious solution but I don't know how to limit the bitshift to the bits of LEFT (0x01) to BOTTOM (0x08).

I hope someone can help me. I'm lost when it comes to bit operations.

Comment: Any reason you don't want to use an enum and EnumSet instead?

Comment: This is for performance reasons. I'm coding games for mobile platforms.

Comment: Have you tried using EnumSet and found it to be a bottleneck?

Comment: No, I'm sorry. I don't know if there are larger performance improvements by using bitshift. This operation may be performed very often during gameplay for many objects (100+), so it seemed easier and faster to just use bitshift.

Comment: *Never* guess with performance. Write the cleanest code which works, test its performance, and see whether it's adequate. If it's not, *then* optimize until it's adequate.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This should do it:

```
connections = ((connections << 1) | (connections >> 3)) & 0x0f;
```

Comment: Thank you! This works really great! For ccw rotation I just had to change left shift into right shift and vice versa!